Cement board hole repair and redrill
Can I patch a hole in a plaster wall which is now too big for my anchor  and drill a new hole in the same spot I am putting up kitchen cabinets.

If you are putting up cabinets they should be anchored into studs and not just wall board.

You cannot use a patched hole.  Second to find the studs and use them.

If you couldn't use a stud for your cabinet mount, you might as well cut open the drywall and put in some blocking, then repair the drywall.  Behind the cabinet the repair doesn't even need to look pretty.

You should patch the hole
You should NOT use drywall to hang cabinets in first place
It is not safe
Find the studs and use those.
If no studs found in the location use methods like French cleat to hang cabinets.
